# All urls not showing up on django.rest_framework documentation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is my main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include_docs_urls(title='Foot The Ball API')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/v1/aggregator/', include('aggregator.urls')),
    url(r'^api/v1/bouncer/', include('bouncer.urls')),

]
```

These are the urls in bouncer.urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    url(r'^register/(?P<location_id>[\w.-]+)/$', RegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
    url(r'^location/$', LocationView.as_view(), name='location'),
]
```

I'm using rest_framework.documentation.
Strangely only login and logout view show up in the documentation home page.
These are the relevant views that are routed to by the urls. This is the login view

```
class LoginView(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        user = authenticate(
            email=request.data.get("email"),
            password=request.data.get("password")
        )
        if not user:
            return Response({
                'status': 'Unauthorized',
                'message': 'Email or password incorrect',
            }, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        login(request, user)
        return Response(UserSerializer(user).data)
```

This is the logout view,

```
class LogoutView(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        logout(request)
        return Response({}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

This is the Register View,

```
class RegisterView(views.APIView):
    def get_or_create(self, request, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=request.data.get("email"))
            return Response(user, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            location = Location.objects.get(id=kwargs.get('location_id'))
            serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                user = serializer.save()
                user.location = location
                user.save()
                subject = "Please Activate Your FootTheBall Account!"
                token = self._generate()
                link = HOST + PREFIX + str(user.id) + SUFFIX + token
                message = 'Please use the following link to activate your account.\n\n{}'.format(link)
                from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
                to_list = [user.email, 'soumasish@foottheball.com']
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email, to_list, fail_silently=True)

                Token.objects.create(user=user, token=token)
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            else:
                return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def _generate(self):
        return ''.join(random.choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for _ in range(32))
```

And this is the location view,

```
class LocationView(views.APIView):
    def get_or_create(self, request):
        try:
            location = Location.objects.get(country=request.data.get("country"), city=request.data.get("city"))
            Response(location, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Location.DoesNotExist:
            serializer = LocationSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            else:
                Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The last two views dont show up.
Can someone help as to what's going on here?

Comment: something in your `RegisterView` and `LocationView` is different

Comment: Does your urls work for location, register, aggregator and bouncer?

Comment: @doniyor I've updated the question with the views.

Comment: @Walucas the urls dont work either I'm getting Method not allowed.

Comment: post your urls.py, I think you forgot to register the methods

Comment: @Walucas the urls.py is already there. That's all the code there is.

Comment: do me a favor, please try to access: `http://yourhost/BLABLA` and type the output as an image, so we will see all urls already generated

Answer (score 1):

you must implement `get()` or `post()` methods in the last two views otherwise they are not valid views for APIView as stated here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/

Comment: So I have the get_or_create method. I don't need any additional method over get_or_create, do I still need to implement get and post, and then how will they work. As in I only want get_or_create.

Comment: you can implement the same flow in `post` as well but it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to register the urls with Routers?

e.g:

```
from rest_framework import routers
routes = routers.DefaultRouter()

routes.register(r'location', LocationView)
urlpatterns += api_routes.urls
```

documentation: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/